# Python Fewest Lines Challenge (HOTPO/Collatz)

Tags: python

The [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), otherwise known as Half Or Triple Plus One (HOTPO), takes any positive integer n to start.

If n is even, divide it by two. If n is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1. The conjecture is that no matter what number you start with, it will always reach 1.

The challenge is to write a program that outputs all the values of n as well as the number of steps it took. For example, with n = 3, the output should be:

```
3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
Finished. 7 steps required.
```

My best attempt takes 6 lines:

```
x = [3]
while x[-1] != 1:
    if x[-1] % 2 == 1: x.append(3*x[-1]+1)
    x.append(x[-1]/2)
for num in x: print num
print "Finished. " + str(len(x)-1) + " steps needed."
```

What is the minimum number of lines required to generate this output for any reasonably-sized n? Can my code be further reduced?

Comment: I don't think that shorter should be an objective in itself. The two objectives should be: efficient and readable.

Comment: This question is likely better suited for codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: Here is a link to a collatz golf solution in python: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12209

Comment: Thanks @OmnipotentEntity, will make a note of that for next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some improvements making use of the lambda function:

```
x=[3]
while x[-1] != 1:
    x.append((lambda n: n%2==0 and n/2 or 3*n+1)(x[-1]))
    print(x[-1])
print "Finished. " + str(len(x)-1) + " steps needed."
```

I just stick more code in one line, and there is now only one loop instead of two, printing can be done from the same loop as calculating.

Or since it is for least number of lines, you can use two one line loops and get it in 3 lines:

```
x=[3]
while x[-1]!=1: x=(lambda y: y+[(lambda n: n%2==0 and n/2 or 3*n+1)(x[-1])])(x)
print("\n".join([str(y) for y in x])+"\nFinished. {} steps required.".format(len(x)-1))
```

With thanks to Pythonista for that last line :)

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even think of that. However, like @OmnipotentEntity mentioned, there is a single-line solution over on codegolf: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12209

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write it in three lines without the use of lambda function because they are unnecessary for a variable that can be referenced.

```
x = [3]
while x[-1] != 1:x.append((3*x[-1]+1) if x[-1] % 2 == 1 else (x[-1]/2))
print("\n".join([str(num) for num in x])+"\nFinished. " + str(len(x)-1) + " steps needed.")
```